# Split string into formula not working?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I'm new in crystal report.I want to split string from field data ,Ex. data is "aa : dasdas^bb : dasdas^cc : dasdasd^dd : dsadasd^"

And this is my code in crystal report with basic syntax.

```
Dim xvs1() as string
Dim xresult as string

if isnull({Field_Data}) = false then
   xvs1 = Split({Medical.mr_vs} , "^")
   xresult = xvs1(1)
   formula = xresult
end if
```

Output in crystal report : "aa : dasdas^bb : dasdas^cc : dasdasd^dd : dsadasd^" ,Process is not split, and error not found in my solution, Please help Thank you so much.

Comment: are you using basic syntax or crystal syntax